# Convert Umbraco IContent to JSON

Tags: c#, json, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a handle on an `IContent` object(s) from Umbraco through a listener even on publish

```
public static IContent[] FaqEntities(this PublishEventArgs<IContent> publishEventArgs)
        {
            return publishEventArgs.PublishedEntities.Where(x => x.ContentType.Name == "FAQ").ToArray();
        }
```

Within C#, I want to create a `JSON` file containing selected properties (alias and value) from the published documents in the array I return - is there a simple way to serialize an Umbraco `IContent` object to get the JSON output I require?

`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(faqEntities)` and  `var json = Json.Encode(faqEntities)` just gives me the entire object but I wish to create a JSON file similar to

```
{
    "faqs": [{
            "nodeId": 1,
            "question": "My Password is incorrect?",
            "answer": "If you have forgotten or lost your password, please click on the Forgotten Password link on the Login page and follow the instructions shown."
        },
        {
            "nodeId": 2,
            "question": "How can I edit my personal details?",
            "answer": "You can blah blah blah....."
        },
        {
            "nodeId": 3,
            "question": "What is an ABC?",
            "answer": "An ABC is where you can....."
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a simple way once the IContent is retrieved to convert to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create classes to define the json you desire, and then you can select into the new format. Something like:

```
public class Faq
{
     public int nodeId { get; set; }
     public string question { get; set; }
     public string answer { get; set; }
}

public class FaqCollection
{
     public IList<Faq> faqs { get; set; }
}
```

Then populate the object:

```
var faqsCollection = new FaqCollection();
faqsCollection.faqs = faqEntities.Select(y => new Faq { nodeId = y.nodeId, question = y.question, answer = y.answer }).ToList();
```

Depending on your needs you may not even have to convert to json before doing this.